# Total amount of connections to a WiFi hot spot Android Phone

Tags: android, mobile

I ran my phone as a WiFi Hot Spot yesterday, but it seems it only allows a total of 8 users, is that the same for other model models? don't worry about my model, just want to know if 8 is the total because I'm creating a application for Android mobile devices.

Canvas

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Google help [page](http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2677717), you are correct, only 8 simultaneous connections are allowed.

> You can also share your data connection with up to 8 devices at once, by turning it into a portable Wi-Fi hotspot.